# htbp and longtable

Tags: tables, page-breaking, longtable

I am applying a `longtable` environment. 
I would like to use something like `[htbp]` in order to put the table in the next page. Every time I do it gives me an error. 
Now I am solving the problem with a simple `\pagebreak`. Do you know a better solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

`longtable`has no such options because it makes no sense to have a longtable in a floating object. You can use only `[lcr]` as option for the environment `longtable` for the horizontal alignment. Use `\newpage` if you want to start the `longtable` on the next page. And, of course, do *not* put the `longtable`environment in a `table`environment.

Answer (score 5):

If you are forcing the page break anyway probably better to use `\clearpage` rather than `\newpage` to prevent any tables floating past the `longtable` and getting out of order.

If you want to avoid a forced page break and want `longtable` to move to a natural page break (and you are feeling brave) you can do

```
\usepackage{afterpage}
```

Then

```
\afterpage{\clearpage\begin{longtable}.......\end{longtable}}
```

If the table is very long it might be better (and certainly take up less TeX memory) if you put (just) the longtable in a separate file, say `mytable.tex` then

```
\afterpage{\clearpage\input{mytable}}
```